# Fabric js React: Drag shape from button and drop on Canvas not able to place on mouse drop position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

i am trying to drag rectangle shape from the button and to drop it on any position of canvas. But it's not able to put in particular position, it's on different position. I am using fabric js with react.

[image]

This is my example of react code

```
const App2 = () => {
    const fabricRef = React.useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const initFabric = () => {
            fabricRef.current = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current);
        };

        const disposeFabric = () => {
            fabricRef.current.dispose();
        };

        initFabric();
        return () => {
            disposeFabric();
        };
    }, []);

    const [posa, setPosA] = React.useState(1);
    const [posb, setPosB] = React.useState(1);


    const handleDragEvent = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addRectangle1(posa, posb)
    };

    const addRectangle1 = (x: any, y: any) => {
        const rect = new fabric.Rect({
            top: x,
            left: y,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            fill: "red"
        });

        fabricRef.current.add(rect);
    };

    return <div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-3 mt-8">
            <Button draggable="true"

                onDragCapture={(e: any) => {

                    let rect = canvasRef?.current.getBoundingClientRect();
                    let scaleX = canvasRef.current.width / rect.width;
                    let scaleY = canvasRef?.current.height / rect.height;
                    setPosB((e.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY);
                    setPosA((e.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX);

                }}
                onDragEnd={(e) => handleDragEvent(e)}

                variant="outlined" >Add rectangle</Button>
        </div>
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="800" height="600" className="border-dashed border-2 border-sky-500" />
    </div>;
};

export default App2;
```

i am using the concept from [this](https://codepen.io/Prebyter/pen/ggVxWo)